# How to set the binding of an itemscontrol to a different ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext, itemscontrol

I've been trying to bind a list to my ItemsControl and continually come up with binding issues so I've come for help.

My code so far is:

```
...
<ssm:RecentFilesViewModel x:Key="RecentFilesVM" />
...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecentFilesVM}, Path=Files} Margin="0 4 0 0">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Width="285">
                <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 2" Text="{Binding Path}" />
            </telerik:RadRibbonButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

I can get the list to appear if I set the datacontext to the entire window BUT it means all of my other bindings don't work. This is the only object that requires this viewmodel so I want to set it unique to this ItemsControl. Can somebody please help me get this working? It's slowly driving me insane.

EDIT:

I currently have it this way because there is no direct view model for the other objects. We're trying to keep this as decoupled as possible so there is no window datacontext. Everything else works just fine. I am using PRISM and Telerik.

By adding the binding source, all of my command bindings (which connect to another class in another project) no longer work. Is there a way I can make sure my binding source is kept specific to the object I am manipulating?

Comment: Why you need to keep decoupled ViewModel with View?

Comment: Our aim is to make the software as decoupled as possible. We make a lot of similar applications so we want to be able to easily use code in multiple places without too much reworking. By keeping it decoupled, we can easily say 'hey, this is our standard shell' and copy the project to then just hook it up to the other components in the other software projects.

Comment: But when you are decoupling  ViewModel with View, Don't you lose characteristics or advantages of MVVM model?
If you want decoupled this parts, you would introducing shell into View?

Comment: That's something I haven't really explained. We have our main view (we call it app) and then we have this view which is called the shell. The shell is then injected into the main view. There is no functionality in the shell. Anything that is functionality is bound to something else: eg. commands are in another project which are bound to using markup extensions (x:Static commands:appcomands.savecommand).

Comment: I am starting to understand more your programming model, since this moment is the first time that I hear this model.
If all is clear, you need to create List into xmal and in this view (or xmal) you need to bind this list with StaticResource, it isn't?

Comment: Our main aim is to make everything as reusable as possible to save work later. Everything is completely decoupled so we have multiple views that are then injected into our shell that have no idea what the data they will be filled with looks like. They don't know anything about the other views in our shell, they just all know what's relevant to them. By doing this, we could say 'I want this to be in this software project' and literally copy it over and it will work instead of trying to refactor it.

Comment: The issue is then interacting with the list. I've been able to make the view model into a resource but by making the list into a resource, it's harder to interact with from the view model, particularly as the view model is in another project.

Comment: if you problem is the binding a List from ViewModel to View, because with resource you already could...
For me, you can do reference between two projects, and after in the project where you have View, you create ObservableCollection, and bind this. Are you know as binding ObservableCollection to View, or Do I put it as answer?

Comment: I have the list working now, it shows. The issue is that by doing this, exactly as I have in the code above, it will no longer bind my objects from a different namespace. I'm not 100% on what happened but the code above seems to have changed the datacontext somehow...

Comment: But if you DataContext change, your others bindings would fail. Is most probably that have happened  with your list. Can you verify the DataContext or List in the other project?

Comment: The bindings are failing, that's what I'm saying. By adding `Source={StaticResource RecentFilesVM}` the other bindings no longer work. That's the issue. I'm not sure how that small piece of code suddenly makes all of my bindings fail.

Comment: If when you refer with other bindings to The Binding that are into ItemsControl. The reason by which this happened is the Source have the list of some object, and into the ItemsControl you Binding each property of object that are into List. If you new list not have the properties you are binding into ItemsControl your bindings will breaking. For the more Bindings outside  of ItemsControl should not fail

Comment: That's what's confusing. Items outside of my ItemsControl are suddenly failing. I can understand if I had things inside the itemscontrol that were failing but it's things outside of it.

Comment: In this case the problem is really rare. Try reviewing your code in Syntax. After, make a easy binding with TextBlock or Button, for see if the problem continue. Try with DynamicResource instead to Static. The last, try writing `ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFilesViewModel.Files}`

Comment: I've tried just binding the same way to a textblock and the same thing happens. I can't make it dynamic and as written as a comment to another person, binding that way sadly doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Add a property for the `RecentFilesViewModel` inside the `ViewModel` of the Window's `DataContext`.

Then, you can simply do:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFilesViewModel.Files}" Margin="0 4 0 0">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton Width="285">
                <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 2" Text="{Binding Path}" />
            </telerik:RadRibbonButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Edit:

Based on your recent edit, you can try wrapping the ItemsControl in a Grid, and set its DataContext to RecentFiles. Note, you do not have to create a resource/key for RecentFiled, you can simply access it as long as the namespace is defined.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <ssm:RecentFilesViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Files} Margin="0 4 0 0">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadRibbonButton Width="285">
                    <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 2" Text="{Binding Path}" />
                </telerik:RadRibbonButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: There is no direct viewmodel for the window, it has no datacontext. All of the other items in the window are referred to using markup extensions like x:Static. We're trying to keep the main window as decoupled from everything as possible to make it easier to expand later. I've tried {Binding ssm:RecentFilesViewModel.Files} but that doesn't work either. (ssm standing for the namespace the RecentFilesViewModel class is in)

Comment: The whole point of a view model is to provide data to the view. As soon as you set the datacontext of the ItemsControl to the view model, you have coupled the view model. You might as well couple it at the Window and use the view model as it is intended to be used. If you truly want decoupling, you should take a look at Prism and Unity. You can potentially make your app more difficult to maintain in the long run trying to work around coupling to view models than just using them like they are intended to be used.

Comment: That makes sense but we're trying not to do that. I didn't mention we are using PRISM and telerik co-operatively. I've updated my code above to what I've managed to work so far now but I'm still having issues.